# Copy large amount of data from ms access table (with 2.3 mimion recs) to sql 2000 server using ADO in VB6

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb6, ms-access-2000

i have a  ms access (2.3 mimion recs) table and need to copy to sql server 2000 DB, every day i have new 15000 Recs to be imported to sql server 2000

so i need a sql statement NOT  a loop to copy data from access to sql.

using vb6, ado

Comment: What does "mimion" mean? "million"? And, which operating system are you running? Windows Server 2000?

Comment: Google suggest Minions. I'd hope there are more then 2 :)

Answer (score 0):

Copying 15,000 from Access to Sql daily even a row at a time should not be a significant problem in terms of performance, etc.

However, you could [connect to the Jet provider from inside SQL server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175866(v=sql.105).aspx) and then treat the Access data just like any other ODBC linked server from inside SQL server.

Just in case you see references to an ACE driver -- The Ace driver replaces the Jet Driver in newer version of Access.

Personally, I would still use a client based app to simply load the 15K records and not connect sql server to Jet. If I needed more performance, maybe, but not for 15K records daily.